# Cannot access colors from resources via R.color.x

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a color list under values/colors.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorConnected">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

When trying to use the color from my code like this:

```
context?.getColor(R.color.colorConnected)
```

The compiler cannot resolve the color name:

> Unresolved reference: colorConnected

PS: Using the color in other XML files works fine (e.g. "@color/colorConnected").

Comment: Are you positive that you imported the correct "R"?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the top(in imports section) and

> 1. find import .....R and remove it.
> 2. move to the place where R is being used, it must be Red colored.
> 3. Click on the R and import.

This will solve your issue.

Comment: I believe this answer needs a bit of explanation: There is a possibility that you imported com.android.R which contains colors like "background_dark" and [many others](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color), but won't contain colors you declared in your app's resources, following the actions @Rahul posted should replace the import's source with something like: com.example.yourpackage.R

Answer (score -3):

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.idname);
```

OR

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

OR

```
ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.your_color, null); //without theme

ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.your_color, your_theme); //with theme
```

Comment: How this would help with `Unresolved reference: colorConnected` ?